# Query embedded object with AND in mongodb

Tags: java, mongodb, driver

Let's say there is:

```
{username : "tom1", address : { type : 0, year : 2001 }}
{username : "tom2", address : { type : 1, year : 2011 }}
{username : "tom3", address : { type : 0, year : 2031 }}
{username : "tom4", address : { type : 1, year : 2002 }}
```

I'm using Java Driver, how can I query:
users who's address.type = 1 AND address.year > 2010 ?

Notice it is in the address object, so normal query `{address.type : 1, address.year : {$gt : 2010}}` does not work at all.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Oh I got it:

```
{address : {type : 1, year : {$gt : 2010}}}
```